# Weird behaviour with sockets on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, c++, sockets

I have two .net applications communicating with sockets on port 5672 and everthing works fine. 
On server side, i open the connection with this simple code lines:

```
IPAddress localAddr = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];  
TcpListener socket = new TcpListener(localAddr, 5672);  
socket.Start();
```

If i try to launch another server app, it fails, telling me that the port is already in use.
I have also the same pair of applications writted in C++ (not by me).
To my surprise, i can launch both C++ and .net server at the same time.

The worst is that my C++ client can´t communicate with my .net server ("connection refused"
error).

To understand my problem, i listed the used ports with the command:

```
netstat -a
```

And in the result i had:
TCP 0.0.0.0:5672    <--- (this is the c++ server)
TCP [::1] :5672     <--- (this is the .net server)

According to my C# code, souldn't localhost address be 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1?
What's happening on my .net server?
Waht's the meaning of [::1] ?

Note:
If i change my code to:

```
IPAddress localAddr = new IPAddress(new byte[]{0,0,0,0});
```

everything works normaly and my C++ client communicate with .net server.

Comment: I'm using Windows Vista. I can´t be sure now, but i think this problem didn´t happen in XP.

Comment: [::1] is an IPv6 loopback address. Maybe your C# server binds to an IPv6 address and C++ client tries to connect to an IPv6 address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run the following code:

```
        IPAddress localAddr = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        IPAddress localAddr2 = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[1];
```

I get the IPV6 address you showed in localAddr, and "127.0.0.1" in localAddr2 (and there are no more entries in `AddressList`). If you want to use IPv4 you must locate and use the correct address by checking the `AddressFamily` property in each `IPAddress` in your list of candidates `AddressList`.

You cannot by default listen on the same  port/address pair from two apps.  If you want to do this (not sure why you would, since this makes the server app that incoming connections hit non-deterministic), then you can do so by setting [ExclusiveAddrUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.exclusiveaddressuse.aspx) to false on your `TcpListener` - note however that you have to do this while the listener is `Stop`-ped.

Since your C++ app uses '0.0.0.0' directly, it behaves differently. It's using the IPV4 address and so no conflict results with your IPV6 C# `TcpListener`.

Answer (score 2):

I used something like this:

```
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);

        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

        foreach (IPAddress ip in ipHostInfo.AddressList)
        {
            AddressFamily af = ip.AddressFamily;
            if (af == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                ipAddress = ip;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];` is binding to the IPv6 loop back address that is why when you set it by hand to the IPv4 loop back it works fine.

try this

```
IPHostEntry host;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
Console.WriteLine("GetHostEntry(\"LocalHost\") returns:");
foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

For windows 7 I get the following result

```
GetHostEntry("LocalHost") returns:
    ::1
    127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 is `IPAddress.Any`, it binds to anything available.